# Why isn't my Basil cutting rooting?

Tags: roots, basil, cuttings, hydroponic

So, 3 days ago I took a cutting from the main stem of my basil plant and replanted it into a cocopeat puck that is placed into some water, a makeshift hydroponic setup. I am making use of filtered, RO water.

While the cutting hasn't wilted or anything, it's been 3 days and there isn't the tiniest root. I'm pretty sure that the cut end of the stem is exposed to moisture and it does seem like the cutting is getting sufficient water. I'm really new to gardening in general so any help would be appreciated.

[image: Here's a picture of the cutting in question.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roots from cuttings can take 10 to 14 days.  Provide high diffuse light and keep the water levels up.  Using filtered water should help as well